# Unable to create model classes from DB schema using reversed engineering using hibernate configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss-tools

I am new to **Hibernate** and trying to create `annotation based Model classes` from `MYSQL` database using `reversed engineering`(i.e, hibernate-configuration option of jBoss).

However after searching I found this link: **http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/**, but this link does not show how to `create annotation based model classes` from `mysql` schema.

I am using Eclipse Kepler and Add the following URL to your Eclipse Kepler 4.3 installation, via:

Help > Install New Software… > Work with:
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler/

Then select the individual features that you want to install:

Could anyone please suggest what else needs to be done? Attached are the screen shot from my eclipse workspace for reference.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Please guide me soonest possible

So it's not giving me any output with annotations, all model classes without mappings are generating with *.hbm files. **Please, Please help**

**I want model classes with hibernate mapping on that (i.e, without .hbm files).**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After researching I was able to solve this issue. I should be creating a JPA project and through JPA Tools options, I can generate Entities from tables.